# How to get the moving window average after grouping by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

First, I want to grouby by the columns, `name`, `group` and `place`. 
Then, I want to get the average value `y` of adjacent two months.
Last, I want to add the average value to the origin dataframe.

`The origin dataframe:`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["Amy", "Amy", "Amy", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob"],
                  "group":[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   "place":['a', 'a', "a", 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b' ],
                   "yearmonth": ["2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03"],
                    "y":[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0]
})

print(df)
```

`Dataframe:`

```
name  group place yearmonth  y
0  Amy      1     a   2019-01  1
1  Amy      1     a   2019-02  2
2  Amy      1     a   2019-03  3
3  Bob      1     b   2019-01  1
4  Bob      1     b   2019-02  2
5  Bob      1     b   2019-03  0
6  Bob      2     b   2019-01  2
7  Bob      2     b   2019-02  0
8  Bob      2     b   2019-03  0
```

`Expected Result:`

```
name  group place yearmonth  y   average_2months
0  Amy      1     a   2019-01  1  nan
1  Amy      1     a   2019-02  2  1.5
2  Amy      1     a   2019-03  3  2.5
3  Bob      1     b   2019-01  1  nan
4  Bob      1     b   2019-02  2  1.5
5  Bob      1     b   2019-03  0  1.0
6  Bob      2     b   2019-01  2  nan
7  Bob      2     b   2019-02  0  1.0
8  Bob      2     b   2019-03  0  0.0
```

`What I tried:`

Now I now how to get the average values of adjacent two months. However, I don't know how to add it to the origin dataframe.

```
tmp = df.groupby(['name', 'group', 'place'])['y'].rolling(2).mean()
print(tmp)
```

`tmp:`

```
name  group  place   
Amy   1      a      0    NaN
                    1    1.5
                    2    2.5
Bob   1      b      3    NaN
                    4    1.5
                    5    1.0
      2      b      6    NaN
                    7    1.0
                    8    0.0
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th level of index is your original index

```
df['new']=temp.reset_index(level=[0,1,2], drop=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, I found that in some case, we'd better add `df = df.sort_values(by = ['name', 'group', 'place'])` , otherwise the column `new` and column `y` do not correspond.